# How to force gutenberg to reload blocks after saving

Tags: block-editor

I have a use case in which I am replacing post_content in `wp_insert_post_data` (i.e. replacing swear words), which I prefer to do in PHP.

While saving works, in gutenberg replacements are only visible after page reload.

Also tried hooking into filter `rest_pre_insert_{$this->post_type}` and data was properly returned in ajax request, but gutenberg editor still didn't update blocks content.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: In GB it's not reloading the page because that's not how the editor works. Rather, GB is telling the site, this is what the page is. What are you trying to do that requires modifying `rest_pre_insert_post_type`? It's always better to ask how to fix a problem rather than how to implement a specific solution to a problem

Comment: @TomJNowell I am not sure we understood each other :) rest_pre_insert didn't work. Gutenberg still didn't catch those changes. I am not asking for implementation - rather advice how to force gutenberg to fetch changes being done server-side on saving post.

Comment: These aren't answers, I still don't know why you're trying to use that hook, what are you trying to do on the `rest_pre_insert_{$this->post_type}` hook? What you're asking for is not how the editor works. It's difficult if not impossible to advise on a solution without knowing what you're trying to achieve on that hook

Comment: I think you totally missed point of the question and put to much attention into this hook. I have never mentioned I need/want to use it. I have mentioned ways that I tried to achieve my goal and it didn't work. Maybe my goal is simply not clear to you. Let me know which part is confusing - I have given sample use case in first sentence.

I put some content into rich text editor (GB). Hit save. It sends request to server. `wp_insert_post_data` replaces bad words with *****. Gutenberg should be able to load those changes (that's why I ask how to force it to reload blocks data from server).

Comment: It wasn't clear to me you wanted to replace swear words in your Q. I was hoping to uncover what you were doing on that hook so I could that figure out. You should edit your questions title to something like "How To Replace Swear Words on Save In The Block Editor". As an aside, what if there was a parameter you needed to pass from PHP to make the editor use the response ( there isn't ), it's better to humour those kind of requests, afterall they may be aware of things you're not. From what I understand though, there is no way to do what you want just in PHP